# Cache-server with high availability

Tags: ehcache

I am pretty new to caching modules. 
In my task, i need to design a cache cluster(of 2 servers). The data from my webapp should hit the cache server(that is in the cluster), and the other server will be for high availability.

I went though the ehcache documentation, but still not clear how to start on this cache-server task.

Can somebody help me in this task or please point me to the relevant link.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.developer.com/open/article.php/3700661/Caching-Solutions-in-Java.htm

go through that link, that will defnitely help you to get started

Comment: If i am not wrong, first i need to setup replication the 2 servers(cachce-servers). This part i am clear, but, how to make my web application to know that cache is on the servers?

Comment: Are you using Hibernate? give me the brief overview of the technologies used in the project? What level of caching are you planning to setup ? is it the View level, database or server side?

Comment: http://www.ehcache.org/documentation/user-guide/configuration  this will give you the document on how to configure the Ehcache at start of a JVM  http://ehcache.org/apidocs/ -  this link gives the list of API where you can use it for the implementation

Comment: caching is at db level. currently i am testing as a Proof of concept. I have a stand alone java programs on 2 laptops(both are connected in the network). i ran the program from one laptop. since its the first time, there will be a miss, and the entry will be added in the cache. Ideally, the cache on the other laptop also should get replicated and, when i ran the program from 2nd laptop, there should be a cache hit. but, thats not happening!

Comment: on node1, this is the configuration  <cacheManagerPeerProviderFactory 
class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheManagerPeerProviderFactory" 
properties="peerDiscovery=manual, rmiUrls=//<node2-IP>:40001/sampleCache2"/>  and on node2, this is the configuration <cacheManagerPeerProviderFactory 
class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheManagerPeerProviderFactory" 
properties="peerDiscovery=manual, rmiUrls=//<node1-ip>:40001/sampleCache1"/>